# get unique id of the device in windows 10 store app c#

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

We have a uwp windows 10 store app and its licensed per device. we throw an error when that license is already applied on any device.  user may uninstall the app and install it again on the same device and same license key works fine.

But for every few days i noticed the HWID(hardwareId ) generated by the following is not unique which fails license key when user uninstalls app and installs on the same device.

```cs
private static string GetId()
{
    var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    var hardwareId = token.Id;
    var dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

    var bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```

From my analysis i feel that the hwid changed for our customers when there were restarts in their computers. though in terms of hardware itself nothing has changed. so device name ,device model,  operating systems everything is same always for those users and only HWID has changed.

Is there a better way to handle one license per one device or generate this hwid uniquely? Is it sensitive to OS build number changes or any other software or firmware updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASHWID provides a strong binding between the app/packag, which is not affected by OS re-installs and version updates for an app. But sometimes there are also [other reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj553431(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#introduction) can affect it, it is difficult to know which causes the change of the ASHWID.

Therefore, if you want to get the unique id to distinguish the device, maybe you could use [SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.getsystemidforpublisher?view=winrt-20348#Windows_System_Profile_SystemIdentification_GetSystemIdForPublisher) method, the identifier returned by this method is specific to the app publisher on the current device. In other words, all apps by the same publisher will get the same value for this ID (for all users).

Comment: when you say for each application package it will be different, does it mean when i upgrade the build number  for the same package, does it return me a new identifier ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.